# Change login URL from /user to /my-url?

Tags: 7, uri

I need to change the login URL from **/user** to **/my-url**

I found this module: [Rename Admin Paths](https://www.drupal.org/project/rename_admin_paths) module. But I think this could be done in other way. Plus, this module has some conflicts with multilingual sites.